# How to do pagination in cqrs

Tags: pagination, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am just started learning CQRS model. So when an action performed on a domain I store that action as event in DB, without updating actual domain. So, I understand that on read side I have to prepare read model by applying all events of given domain and return to client. This is good as long as I am accessing single entity with it's ID. But how could I handle the same in case of paginated data.

Ex: Lets say I have a domain called "Content" and will have actions on that domain for

**Event 1:** STATUS change

**Event 2:** Marking content as Useful by site visiting users

**Event 3:** Assigning content to a user for moderation.

Now my queries will be with page size of 20

**Query 1:** Get me "Content" of status "APPROVED"

**Query 2:** Get me "Content" by User(to whom it's assigned for moderation)

**Query 3:** Get me "Content" by Useful count

And on UI the listed Content should have all information like - To whom it is assigned and it's Useful count irrespective of above queries

If it is like reading all contents one by one and discarding Content entity which is not fit for criteria will end up with reading too much data, right?

And in case of Query 3: Get me "Content" by Useful count - I should read all Content entities exist in DB to decide which has most useful rating.

Please guide me in learning read-side of CQRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have chosen the same domain objects on the write side as you have on the read side. You do not have to do a one to one mapping between these models. You can create different read models from the same domain object depending on how you want to use them.

As I understand it you have created one read model where you can get each Content using an ID. That is fine when you want to show one single Content at the time.

To solve the search problem you could create a new read model that is optimized for searching. You could for example store the values that you want to filter on in a SQL table. These two read models could be completely separated from each other. Since the first model is accessed by a key a key-value store could be used.

> So, I understand that on read side I have to prepare read model by
>   applying all events of given domain and return to client.

You do not have to apply all events. You could just apply the events that you are interested in. You could also apply events from other domain objects.

Comment: You mean for searching I have to generate/update read model on each new event and has to persist into DB and on query side have to query directly read model

Comment: Yes, exactly. That way you will have two different read models optimized for different tasks.